# What is the most efficient way to generate random numbers from a union of disjoint ranges in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, random, range

I would like to generate random numbers from a union of ranges in Kotlin. I know I can do something like

```kotlin
((1..10) + (50..100)).random()
```

but unfortunately this creates an intermediate list, which can be rather expensive when the ranges are large.

I know I could write a custom function to randomly select a range with a weight based on its width, followed by randomly choosing an element from that range, but *I am wondering if there is a cleaner way to achieve this with Kotlin built-ins*.

Comment: If you use a `sequence { ... }`, you can at least save the space for the lists. That's my two cents.

Comment: @Sweeper I agree with you that using a sequence would work for a single call, but I need to generate multiple numbers, which means multiple calls to `random()`. I can store a list in a variable for caching purposes, but as far as I understand using a sequence would iterate through it for each call.

Comment: I often feel like we really miss utils in Java/Kotlin stdlib for creating collection "views". If `IntRange` would have something like `asList()` and we would have a way to concatenate lists by creating a view, this would be really trivial, even using already existing `random()` function. Views would do the trick, they would automatically translate to the proper value. Anyway, if you implement this function by yourself then I think your suggested approach isn't the best one. Just get a random number between 0 and the summed size of both ranges and assign it to one of ranges.

Comment: @broot If I understand you correctly, that _is_ my suggested approach: generate `t` between `1` and `size(range_1) + ... + size(range_n)`, then find `i` such that `size(range_1) + ... + size(range_(i-1)) < t <= size(range_i)`, then choose a random element from `range_i`.

Comment: Ok, so we mean almost the same approach, but I think you don't need to perform additional `random()` which is potentially heavy operation. You can use `t` itself to choose from the selected range. For example, for `(1..10) + (50..100)` we take a random number between 0 and 60, let's say it is 20, then we choose 11th element of second range, which is 60. So we process it like it is a list with size = 61 and we just need to take a random item from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your ranges are nonoverlapped and sorted, if not, you could have some preprocessing to merge and sort.

This comes to an algorithm choosing:

- O(1) time complexity and O(N) space complexity, where N is the total number, by expanding the range object to a set of numbers, and randomly pick one. To be compact, an array or list could be utilized as the container.
- O(M) time complexity and O(1) space complexity, where M is the number of ranges, by calculating the position in a linear reduction.
- O(M+log(M)) time complexity and O(M) space complexity, where M is the number of ranges, by calculating the position using a binary search. You could separate the preparation(O(M)) and generation(O(log(M))), if there are multiple generations on the same set of ranges.

For the last algorithm, imaging there's a sorted list of all available numbers, then this list can be partitioned into your ranges. So there's no need to really create this list, you just calculate the positions of your range s relative to this list. When you have a position within this list, and want to know which range it is in, do a binary search.

```
fun random(ranges: Array<IntRange>): Int {
    // preparation
    val positions = ranges.map {
        it.last - it.first + 1
    }.runningFold(0) { sum, item -> sum + item }

    // generation
    val randomPos = Random.nextInt(positions[ranges.size])
    val found = positions.binarySearch(randomPos)
    // binarySearch may return an "insertion point" in negative
    val range = if (found < 0)  -(found + 1) - 1 else found
    return ranges[range].first + randomPos - positions[range]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Short solution**

We can do it like this:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    println(random(1..10, 50..100))
}

fun random(vararg ranges: IntRange): Int {
    var index = Random.nextInt(ranges.sumOf { it.last - it.first } + ranges.size)
    ranges.forEach {
        val size = it.last - it.first + 1
        if (index < size) {
            return it.first + index
        }
        index -= size
    }

    throw IllegalStateException()
}
```

It uses the same approach you described, but it calls for random integer only once, not twice.

**Long solution**

As I said in the comment, I often miss utils in Java/Kotlin stdlib for creating collection views. If `IntRange` would have something like `asList()` and we would have a way to concatenate lists by creating a view, this would be really trivial, utilizing existing logic blocks. Views would do the trick for us, they would automatically calculate the size and translate the random number to the proper value.

I implemented a POC, maybe you will find it useful:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val list = listOf(1..10, 50..100).mergeAsView()
    println(list.size) // 61
    println(list[20]) // 60
    println(list.random())
}

@JvmName("mergeIntRangesAsView")
fun Iterable<IntRange>.mergeAsView(): List<Int> = map { it.asList() }.mergeAsView()

@JvmName("mergeListsAsView")
fun <T> Iterable<List<T>>.mergeAsView(): List<T> = object : AbstractList<T>() {
    override val size = this@mergeAsView.sumOf { it.size }

    override fun get(index: Int): T {
        if (index < 0 || index >= size) {
            throw IndexOutOfBoundsException(index)
        }

        var remaining = index
        this@mergeAsView.forEach { curr ->
            if (remaining < curr.size) {
                return curr[remaining]
            }
            remaining -= curr.size
        }

        throw IllegalStateException()
    }
}

fun IntRange.asList(): List<Int> = object : AbstractList<Int>() {
    override val size = endInclusive - start + 1

    override fun get(index: Int): Int {
        if (index < 0 || index >= size) {
            throw IndexOutOfBoundsException(index)
        }
        return start + index
    }
}
```

This code does almost exactly the same thing as short solution above. It only does this indirectly.

Once again: this is just a POC. This implementation of `asList()` and `mergeAsView()` is not at all production-ready. We should implement more methods, like for example `iterator()`, `contains()` and `indexOf()`, because right now they are much slower than they could be. But it should work efficiently already for your specific case. You should probably test it at least a little. Also, `mergeAsView()` assumes provided lists are immutable (they have fixed size) which may not be true.

It would be probably good to implement `asList()` for `IntProgression` and for other primitive types as well. Also you may prefer varargs version of `mergeAsView()` than extension function.

As a final note: I guess there are libraries that does this already - probably some related to immutable collections. But if you look for a relatively lightweight solution, it should work for you.